# Change keyboard layout button

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I want to set keyboard layout changing on Super (win) button. How can I do this?
In system params (I think it called so in English version) there is no Super button in the list of shortcuts.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're asking, but by default super can change the page layout.

- `Super + left/right arrow` switch workspace
- `super + down arrow` view windows in current workspace and shows workspace interface.
- `super + up arrow` Toggle full-screen
- `ctrl + super + left/right arrow` window to left or right half of screen
- `shift + super + left/right arrow` move window to different monitor (if you have more than one)
- `super + a` show all windows

Hopefully this answers your question, but if not what behavior are you actually trying to customize?

Comment: No, I mean keyboard layout, for example from English to Russian and from Russian to English

Comment: @Ясижунадиване If you set `Super` as the key that changes your keyboard layout, everytime you use any other keyboard combination that uses `Super` as part of the shortcut, the keyboard layout will change, so I would personally recommend against it.