# Change keyboard layout button shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, release-hera, language, input, keyboard-layout

I want to set keyboard layout changing on Super (win) button. How can I do this? In system params (I think it called so in English version) there is no Super button in the list of shortcuts.

[image: screenshot]

os:elementary OS 5.1 Hera

Comment: For the record, this question is almost identical to [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/change-keyboard-layout-button). Adding a link here in case the answers/comments there may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround via a shell script. You need to save it as .sh file and execute it with custom keyboard shortcuts in settings set to `⌘`+`Space`. Also be sure to disable all current bindings to `⌘`+`Space` before setting your own.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current`" = "uint32 0" ]
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
else
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In elementary OS only the <kbd>Super</kbd> key can be used eighter to see the System keyboard shortcuts(by default) or to launch the applications menu. There is no easy and troubleless way to set different functionalities then these because the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is used for core OS functionalities like seeing all applications, multispace view, by default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> opens the applications menu for example. As you have already found, you can change the keyboard layout shortcut by using System Settings > Keyboard > Layout > Switch Layout and use only the options there.

The way the elementary OS is built is that you do not have so many options that you can change, if you want to change something because you found it more usefull but it is not implemented into an option - the best way is to post an request issue into https://www.github.com/elementary and if the dev team find a reason to do what you want, they will when they have the time to do it. Sometimes people do some hacks to achieve things, but usually they do not work so well, sometimes they do but it is not for a long, because if the dev team do not give you some option usually the reason is because it will lead to a conflict later because they have some other plans to use it for something else but it is not implemented in the public version of the os yet.

Comment: I want to do it now. And do not wait for years when they make me comfortable. I want to do it now as it will be convenient for me. Perhaps for this you need to edit some system files.

Comment: Probably yes, you have to edit some system files. Or there is another option - to use something like xdotool and simulate some of the accepted key combinations with the one you desire. I have really bad experience trying to use Super key to achieve Multitasking View, you can search here on elementary stackexchange for another atempts to replace system shortcuts. Good luck, can you share your results? For example if you succeed, put an answer of your question, and accept it later.